# How can I backup packages from an install I can't currently boot

Tags: grub2, package-management, dpkg, backup

My ssd had a partition problem and I've been unable to repair grub. I can still access the partition with my files on it though so what I want to do is backup the installed packages and reinstall ubuntu.

Normally if I wanted to backup my packages I'd run `dpkg --get-selections`, but that will just return the packages from the liveusb that I'm booting from. Is there any way to specify which ubuntu installation I want to get selections for?

Or if anyone can think of a better way of backing everything up that would be very helpful too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try to chroot into the old partition to do this, but i'm not sure this will work

maybe an easier solution is to just copy the downloaded packages from the old installation to a temporary location (eg. using a live image) by doing something like this:

> cp -r /mnt/var/cache/apt/archives /temporary_backup_location

and after your new installation is done, you can copy the packages in your new /mnt/var/cache/apt/archives folder

hope this helps